# scikit-learn - Convert pipeline prediction to original value/scale

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras, data-science

I've create a pipeline as follows (using the [Keras Scikit-Learn API](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/))

```
estimators = []
estimators.append(('standardize', StandardScaler()))
estimators.append(('mlp', KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=5, verbose=0)))
pipeline = Pipeline(estimators)
```

and fit it with

```
pipeline.fit(trainX,trainY)
```

If I predict with `pipline.predict(testX)`, I (believe) I get standardised predictions.

**How do I predict on `testX` so that `predictedY` it at the same scale as the actual (untouched) `testY` (i.e. NOT standardised prediction, but instead the actual values)?** I see there is an [`inverse_transform` method for Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.inverse_transform), however appears to be for only reverting a transformed `X`.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the `fit` method - I'm now thinking the transforms only occur on the input features `X` and **not** `Y` (hence the fitted model is on non-standardised `Y`), so the `predict` method produces non-standardised predictions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exactly. The StandardScaler() in a pipeline is only mapping the inputs (trainX) of pipeline.fit(trainX,trainY).

So, if you fit your model to approximate trainY and you need it to be standardized as well, you should map your trainY as

```
scalerY = StandardScaler().fit(trainY)  # fit y scaler
pipeline.fit(trainX, scalerY.transform(trainY))  # fit your pipeline to scaled Y
testY = scalerY.inverse_transform(pipeline.predict(testX))  # predict and rescale
```

The inverse_transform() function maps its values considering the standard deviation and mean calculated in StandardScaler().fit().

You can always fit your model without scaling Y, as you mentioned, but this can be dangerous depending on your data since it can lead your model to overfit. You have to test it ;)